# Finding an unknown point

Tags: trigonometry

I have this model:
[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVfpU.jpg

What values do I have:

1) $D_M$

2) $D_L - D_R$

What I can't figure out, is how to calculate the $C$ position represented on this image.

I don't have $D_L$ and $D_R$ individually, just the difference of them.

If you could help with some reference on how I can calculate the $C$ position, I would be grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't determine $C$ just from the difference. There's an entire one-dimensional curve of points that have the same difference of distances; in fact, this is [one of the definitions of a hyperbola](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Difference_of_distances_to_foci).

Comment: P.S.: "one-dimensional" referred to the problem in the plane. If you're doing this in space, there's in fact an entire surface, a hyperboloid (of revolution), with the same difference of distances.